# A torrent client which automatically detects http and related activity from the web browser and reduces its upload/download speed

Tags: browser, bittorrent, browsing, internet-speed

When my torrent client(transmission on ubuntu) is on, I can barely browse the web.

Manually closing the torrent client or reducing its speed every time I use the browser and then bringing it back to normal when I am not browsing the web is too bothersome.

Is there a client which does this automatically?

Comment: You'll need something more than a torrent client.  Because it is more than likely that your torrent client can't see traffic from your browser.

Comment: Yes. Maybe on the lines of the torrent client having a browser extension to inform it when to switch off and when to switch on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like [NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/). It lets you set priorities for the network traffic from different processes. I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it would do what you want.

For a Linux system, try using Wondershaper. Hopefully you're using a Debian based distro, as I'm not sure Wondershaper is in the yum repository.
Install Wondershaper with the command

```
sudo apt-get install wondershaper
```

Then add these lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
up /sbin/wondershaper <interface name> <downspeed> <upspeed>
down /sbin/wondershaper clear <interface name>
```

Wondershaper is already set up with scripts that cause it to prioritize traffic such as HTTP, SSH, and VOIP, while giving a lower priority to bitTorrent traffic.

I'm not at home to test this on my Linux system right now, so I'm not absolutely certain that this is all correct, but [here](http://ubuntu-snippets.blogspot.com/2008/07/easy-network-traffic-shaping-on-your.html) is where I got it from if you need clarification.

Comment: NetBalancer is not automatic, they are looking for something to automatically balance traffic between a bittorrent client and a browser

Comment: Do you not just set the priority for each process and then leave it? That's what it sounded like to me.

Comment: @SaintWacko, This'll work for me if I can set priorities per application and not every time a network-using-process is started. Another point I didn't make clear is that I use linux. Any idea on an app for linux?

Comment: Added some information on an option for Linux. By the way, did you get notified when I edited my answer?

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying this out. About the notification, I got a notification about 'Lazy badgers' answer below, but not for your edit and comments. I need to check if I should be making changes in my account settings.

Comment: @AbhijithMadhav Alright. I've been trying to figure out if I need to comment after I've edited an answer, in order to let the OP know that I made an edit, or if they get alerted to the edit. Let me how wondershaper works. I could use something like that too :)

Comment: @SaintWacko, I got a notification this time after you commented. So I guess you have to comment after you edit. About wondershaper, I've set it up to run. Can't make out yet if it is helping. I'll stay with it for some time and let you know. You should know that I don't have a very fast connection(about 50 KBps download and 10KBPS upload). Maybe the traffic shaper works better for a higher speed.

Comment: Did you make sure to specify your upspeed and downspeed? And it could very well be that traffic shaping isn't going to make much of a difference on a slower connection.

Comment: @SaintWacko, Wondershaper is working. There is a perceptible improvement in my browsing speed.

Comment: Wonderful! Glad I could help. I'll have to get it set up on my Fedora install.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh utorrent do it, AFAIK it has linux-port (know nothing about porting quality)

Comment: 'Fresh'? You mean the latest? also any specific version number?

Comment: @Lazy Badger, Why is this port called utorrent-server? We want a client right?

Comment: @journeyman-geek - BW-control was introduced, as I recall, in 3.0.  "µTorrent Server, an alpha version available immediately for download here, is intended for users seeking a fast, commandline only BitTorrent client with remote web-based management." - quote from form, thus "server" is nlyname